# the len function in while loop makes me add one more item

Tags: python

I am trying to detect if a list has less than or equal to 3 elements. If the number of elements are less than 3 till then you have to add the elements to the list.the while loop i am using makes me add another element to the list. Below is my code;

```
>>> arr = []
>>> len(arr)
0
>>> if (len(arr) <= 3):
      while (len(arr) <= 3):
                number = input("Enter number:")
                print "Please input more numbers."
                arr.append(number)
Enter number:1
Please input more numbers.
Enter number:2
Please input more numbers.
Enter number:3
Please input more numbers.
Enter number:4
Please input more numbers.
>>> len(arr)
4
>>>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is this your full code? Is this from a jupyter notebook?

Comment: The last time the loop is executed, `arr` already had 3 elements before appending.

Comment: Change the `<=` to `<`.

Comment: when you gives `len<=3` the condition  will be true when its already appended 3 elements. So it will again adds one more . so remove that =

Answer (score 2):

`len(arr) <= 3` this condition will satisfy for the list with 3 elements also. So it will add another element.

If you want to create a list with length, `3`. Change the condition to this. `len(arr) < 3` or `len(arr) <= 3`